# sas logical operators not functioning as expected

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have a condition which follows this logic Av(B^C) which is equivalent to (AvB) ^ (AvC).

Where:

```
A = NAF> 2  
B= (COUNT_INT + COUNT_NOINT < 25)  
C= (NAF> 1)
```

This is the condition given in the specs:

```
NAF> 2   OR  (( COUNT_INT + COUNT_NOINT < 25) AND (NAF> 1))
```

This is how I coded it in sas, but its not producing the correct results. I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Actually this is where it fails when I code up the array :

```
if (sum(count_int_arr[i],count_nonint_arr[i]) lt 25 )  and 
   ( naf_arr[i] gt 2)  or  (naf_arr[i] gt 1) then check_naf_arr[i] = "bad";
```

Comment: Could you give an example where it produces incorrect results? And maybe post the whole code? Tried to reproduce this with some sample values, always worked for me...

Comment: Also you have count_no*n*int in your bottom line, count_noint in the others, there is a n to much, maybe that is the error or is this just a typo in your post?

Comment: (AvB)^(AvC) not (AvB) ^ (BvC).

Comment: Joe, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Maybe the priority of operators playing tricks on you?

Comment: Please suggest an alternative...I tried several variations but didn't find one that works.

Comment: Is there a typo error in your array statement?  "(naf_arr[i] gt 2)" appears twice.  So it seems to read:  if B and A or A

Comment: sorry another typo...i corrected it thanks

Comment: Your logic looks ok.  A or (B and C) has the same result logically as B and C or A.   But you seem to be using an array.  How do you want to aggregate over the elements of the array.  Without other code your current logic is setting the result to BAD if the condition is met for ANY element of the array.

Comment: I think you still have a typo, the array code now reads - if B and A or C.  I think what you are trying to do is - if B and C or A.  Kudos to Dominic below for his excellent exposition of how the logic is working in the different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you coded it is not what you gave in the initial specs. Your code is equivalent to `(A AND B) OR C`, whereas you want `A OR (B AND C)`.

[image: Logical table]

This should give you correct results:

```
DATA myData;

  /* (...) */

  DO i = 1 TO someValue;
    IF (naf_arr[i] > 2) OR (SUM(count_int_arr[i], count_nonint_arr[i]) < 25 AND naf_arr[i] > 1)
        THEN check_naf_arr[i] = "bad";
  END;

  /* (...) */

run;
```